# Rust: Create editable CLI input

Tags: rust

To read user input in rust, we can do this:

```rs
use std::io;
let mut input = String::new();
print!("Edit username: ");
io::stdout().flush().ok();
io::stdin().readline(&mut input);
```

What I want is a way to create editable input text, like filling the stdin with some text that the user can edit. Something like this:

```
  stdout              stdin
     |                  |
Edit username: <existing username>
```

Comment: I do not think this is possible. You can write to the stdin by opening it as a file yourself but writing to it also moves the cursor forward so you can no longer edit it. Terminals provide the edit functionality by putting user text in a separate buffer and only giving it to stdin on user entering newline.

Comment: On second thought, you might be able to do this by putting the terminal in raw mode and handling all user event processing yourself. But unless you are already implementing a full TUI, I suggest just putting the initial value in brackets and letting the user either type the new value or press enter to use the existing one.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm a beginner using this language, so I guess second approach will work, if the first one is way too complicated.

Comment: Or there are crates that may help. Search for [`tui` on crates.io](https://crates.io/search?q=tui).

Comment: @omar either way, be aware that what you are asking for is not trivial, in any language. That's just not a usecase that stdin/stdout was designed for.

Comment: I would expect curses to help with this https://github.com/ihalila/pancurses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are OK with using an external crate, and you don't need the full terminal UI capabilities of something like `tui` (which depends on `termion` or `crossterm`), you can use [`rustyline`](https://crates.io/crates/rustyline).

```rust
use rustyline::{DefaultEditor, Result};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut rl = DefaultEditor::new()?;
    const DEFAULT_USERNAME: &str = "admin";
    let input = rl.readline_with_initial("Edit username: ", (DEFAULT_USERNAME, ""))?;
    println!("Your selected username: {input}");
    Ok(())
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Credit to [this answer (How do I enable editable user input for a Rust terminal application?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46365193/8535397)